# Should EF 6 SetInitializer delete ALL tables?

Tags: entity-framework

I am trying to learn EF 6 Code First. Going through a tutorial online, I went to add a simple string porperty to a class. I then added code to the global.asax, Application_Start method to update the database.

```
Database.SetInitializer(New DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges(Of myDBContext))
```

I though this would only recreate the tables referenced in that context. However, ALL tables (including aspnet tables and tables I manually created) were killed. And only those referenced in this context were recreated. What did I do wrong? Also, couldn't I just have updated the database using Update-Database command in Migrations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The initializer was not called "DropCreate**Tables**IfModelChanges", **it drops the entire database** then creates a new empty database and starts populating it from scratch.

You likely want the initializer [`CreateDatabaseIfNotExists`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679221(v=vs.113).aspx) which will create a database if one does not exist but if one does exist it will not remove it. However with this approach you need to [enable migrations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591621.aspx) so your code knows what to do when it sees a old version of the database and knows what commands to execute it to update it from the old version of the schema to the new version of the schema.

Comment: Thank you. Couldn't I just have done an Update-Database in the Package Manager Console window?

Comment: Possibly, I have not done it that way myself, I have only created migrations.